MUI Autocomplete loses focus when try to close it and opens again
i use a MUI Autocomplete component with React which is not closing correctly. When i want to close it, it loses the focus and then opens again. My example on codeSandbox works but not within my application.
Here my simple MUI Autocomplete:
<Autocomplete
        options={["The Godfather", "Pulp Fiction"]}
        sx={{width: 300}}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie"/>}
      />

My package conf
 "@mui/material": "^6.1.2",


Any Ideas what could be the problem?
Thanks

There must be more to this - I tried the same code provided here in sandbox and it works as expected. What else is there in the code? It will help if you can create a sandbox link to replicate the issue.

in my sandbox example it works too. There must be something within my application whats different but i could not figure out what. I need some hints what could it be. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/column-moving-redux-44t6ds?workspaceId=e99defb7-1292-400c-ae9c-d4d04d6b10ea

Is the sandbox link for the issue? The autocomplete seems to work there. If you want help you will have to provide the steps and code to produce the issue.
